# Network Environment Monitoring Software

Tags: network-monitor, monitoring

I am looking for software to monitor my entire network. I would prefer open source software however, I am also open to a paid solution.

I would want to be able to view all of my servers and to be notified if a drive dies or if there is an issue in the event logs. I would need to see the 'health' of a server. This is primarily for servers however, it would be great to manage workstations too.

Answer (score 3):

You can take the software [Anturis](http://www.anturis.com), which is free up to 5 monitors,  with the ability to monitor various servers and all possible metrics. The alerts are effective:sms, emil and phone. There are troubleshooting options for people who don't feel like real experts.

Answer (score 2):

We use [nagios](http://www.nagios.org/).  So far I haven't found something I can't monitor either via a pre-existing plugin or writing my own if I want to monitor something unusual.  It is free and well documented.

In my experience Nagios has been easy to learn. Anytime I want to monitor something new (new status, not new computer) I first check to see if there is already a plugin for it. In the case of dying drives, there are a handful of SMART status plugins that will report the current status of the SMART check and send a warning if something is amiss. For the health of the server, it depends on what you mean but our standard template monitors load, disk space, system temperature, and ping. We also have checks for SSH, HTTP, MySQL, and a bunch of other services that we add as needed.

One of the biggest advantages is that Nagios/NRPE will accept pretty much anything assuming it is in the right format. For issues with the logs if you can automate processing it in the language of your choice (custom script, plugin, or tool of your choice), you can monitor it. I monitor for failed SSH logins and input/output errors using a simple bash script.

Comment: For someone knowing Nagios this might be clear – but not to others: How does Nagios meet the requirements (notifications for "dying drives", issues in the event logs, showing a health state of the server)? Are there any "cons" (e.g. complexity)? Is it "easy to learn"? Thanks in advance for additional details :)

Comment: Nathan, please [edit] your answer and include details directly :)

Answer (score 1):

You use [GRR](https://github.com/google/grr) to set up a task on each server/workstation that was running [python](http://python.org) with [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil).

- Free, Libre & FOSS
- Cross Platform
- Does a lot more than you are asking for

[image: GRR Logo]

Answer (score 1):

Among the free software I can think of the [spiceworks](http://www.spiceworks.com/app/). it's rather useful, although needs some time to make all the settings

In my organization we use [10-strike lanstate](http://www.10-strike.com/lanstate/). it's not free, but for us it's issential that it allows drawing the map of our network. So we can view all the devices that are monitored on the map - where they are situated